# Итерация в функции происходит только один раз

Tags: python, циклы, for

Почему итерация происходит в функции только один раз? Выдает только первый ключ и его значение. Вне функции итерация происходит полностью

```py
def dict_ru(my_dict):
    for item in my_dict.items():
        return item


my_di = {'name': 'pavel', '34': '123'}


print(dict_ru(my_di))
```

Comment: ну так у вас код в функции `dict_ru` возвращается из цикла на первой же итерации, какой результат вы ожидаете?

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрите для примера такой код:

```py
def dict_ru(my_dict):
    for item in my_dict.items():
        yield item

my_di = {'name': 'pavel', '34': '123'}

print(*dict_ru(my_di))
```

Вывод:

```
('name', 'pavel') ('34', '123')
```

`return` сразу прекращает работу функции, используйте `yield`, чтобы вернуть несколько результатов, и `*`, чтобы проитерироваться по всем этим результатам.

Comment: Или мб `return [item for item in my_dict.items()]` или `return list(my_dict.items())` :)

Comment: @gil9red можно просто `my_dict.items()` :)

Comment: @gil9red Оно понятно, но у человека вопрос именно как в цикле возвращать что-то частями, если я правильно понимаю )

Comment: @Danis И функцию не писать, да )

Comment: Спасибо=).Получилось, сделал как написал @gil9red.

Comment: @Danis, да, но там есть нюанс `items` вернет тип `dict_items`, который нельзя менять и к которому нельзя по индексам обращаться :)